# Nested Attributes in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, nested-attributes, nameerror

I have an app where the user can build a project which will have up to 12 volunteer time slots where other users can sign up to work on the project.

When a project is created, the user is asked for the default (beginning) time.  This default time (Project_Times model) should be written to the `begin_time` in the `Projects` table.its own table in the database, using the project_id parameter to identify which project it belongs to.

The user can then add up to 11 more time slots if they want/need to after the `@project` is created.

I am having a hard time getting the project to create the default time.  This is what I have:

++ Projtime (projtime.rb) Model ++

```
class Projtime < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :start_time, ...
  belongs_to :project
  default_scope :order => 'times.amount ASC'
end
```

++ Project (project.rb) Model ++

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :project_category
  has_many :projtimes, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :projtimes

  def projtimes
    Projtimes.where('project_id=?', id)
  end
end
```

++ Projects Controller ++

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @project = current_user.build_project(params[:project])
    @project.save
    @render 'edit'
  end
```

where the project is automatically assigned to the user using the syntax above.  I have tried to copy the same concept (factoring in the fact that there are multiple times for each project) and come up with this for the `ProjtimesController`:

```
class ProjtimesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    @project.projtimes.build
  end
end
```

However, I'm getting a `NameError in ProjectsController#new`

with `uninitialized constant Project::Projtimes`

I would think that with setting the `belongs_to` and `has_many` associations, this should work.

Help anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

projtime.rb should start with `class Projtime` not `class Projime`.

A second set of eyes :-)

Comment: typo in posting to the Stack.  Not the real problem...  Thanks, though.  Edited.

Comment: And the 'def projtimes' in Project will mask the the method of the same name generated by the has_many.

Comment: That was it.  Interesting that a duplicate namespace will interfere with the method generation.